# Game assets sometimes doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I installed the game project on my device and it ran perfectly, but when i open it in my device without plug in the device to xcode, sometimes some of the assets don't appear. I don't know what the problem is. Has anyone faced it before?

Comment: Does it work fine when it is connected to your test device?

Comment: @RUON Could be a problem related to zPositions?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app off of your test device and then run your app again.

After it successfully works with it being connected. Disconnect it and it should work.